# python-pygame rectangle won't draw/render

Tags: python, pygame

im relatively new to coding and after understanding some basics in python i'm trying to apply oop in pygame
I have this code and I can't figure out why the rectangle won't appear

```
import pygame
import time

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
pygame.display.set_caption("EXAMPLE")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)
FPS = 30

class Puddles(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    puddle_width = 100
    puddle_height = 20
    def __init__(self,color,x,y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.color = color
        self.image = pygame.Surface((Puddles.puddle_width,Puddles.puddle_height))
        self.image.fill(self.color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = self.x # i think problem's here because if I type specific integers for x and y the tile will appear
        self.rect.y = self.y

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
puddle1 = Puddles(red, 400, 600)
all_sprites.add(puddle1)
gameExit = False

while not gameExit:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        print event

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True

all_sprites.update()
screen.fill(white)
all_sprites.draw(screen)
pygame.display.flip()


pygame.quit()
quit()
```

any ideas?
thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
puddle1 = Puddles(red, 400, 600)
```

The y position of the puddle is below the screen height, so it's outside of the screen. ;) Try to change it for example to `puddle1 = Puddles(red, 400, 200)`.

Also, lines 43-46 should be indented, so that they're in the while loop.

Comment: oh thanks dude! what a silly mistake i  made! because (400,600)(600 is  the edge)i put those numbers randomly and i wanted to check if it works

Comment: and lines 43-46 accidentally are there because this is the first time im asking a question. thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Aris I'm glad I could help you! :) Please upvote and accept.

Comment: i cant upvote it wont allow me # Once you a earn a total of 15 reputation your votes will change the publicly displayed score

Comment: No problem, I just need 4 more points to unlock commenting. Not being able to write comments is rather annoying.